# Can't install python modules

Tags: python

I have a problem with the following command:

> setup.py install.

I know it should work, I have tried it on a laptop but I don't have access to it at the moment. I need to complete a homework so I tried the same on my PC. And when I type the same command into cmd it just runs pyscripter as if I would use right click on setup.py and click edit with pyscripter. It does nothing else. I am sure that I am in the right folder in cmd.

My python version is 2.7 and my pyscripter version is v2.5.3. My OS is win7. I have tried to install other modules but I get the same response.

Has anyone encountered the same problem? I have searched the internet but I haven't found any answers to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you installed Python 2.7 in the default folder i.e. `c:\python27`, then you can type:

```
c:\python27\python setup.py install
```

Wherever you installed it, you should append that path to your PATH variable (you'll need to log on as an admin to do that).

Answer (score 1):

Do `python setup.py install` instead.

Windows is probably not set up to recognize `.py` files as executable.

Comment: It also doesn't work. It says, that python is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. How do I set up Windows to recognize .py as an executable ?

Comment: Actually nevermind, thank you for your help. I would have never thought that it would be a mistake with runing the file. I have changed the open with option to pyscripter and that is why running it caused the editor to open. Thank you very much for your help, it has shown me the direction in which my problem was. :) 
I have solved the problem, just had to change the open with to python.

Answer (score 1):

Recently our class at school used all of the above programs. about a handful of students had trouble installing like you described. Fortunally I didnt not have this problen but I can suggest you use Administration priviledges.

> Make sure you download the correct version.
>
> Go to your download folder and look at the file you have downloaded (do this via my computer not from your web browser)
>
> Right click on the file and then click run as an administrator

Answer (score 1):

Here is an awesome site for windows binaries: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

If the library you need is there, just download and install like any other windows program...